# How can I use purrr to match records from a lookup table?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have this dataset

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(Q1= c('AL', NA, 'TX', 'FL'), Q2=c('MN', 'CO', NA, NA), value=c(10,24,12,54)) 
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     Q1    Q2 value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1    AL    MN    10
2  <NA>    CO    24
3    TX  <NA>    12
4    FL  <NA>    54
```

And I am trying to use `purrr` to convert the values in `Q1` and `Q2` into full state names using a lookup table

```
lktState <- data_frame(abb=state.abb, name=state.name)
```

So far I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
data_frame(Q1= c('AL', NA, 'TX', 'FL'), Q2=c('MN', 'CO', NA, NA), value=c(10,24,12,54)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars('Q1','Q2'), purrr::map(.x = ., lktState$name[match(.x, lktState$abb)]))
```

> Error in match(.x, lktState$abb) : object '.x' not found

Comment: This is one way to do it, `df %>% gather(var, abb, -value) %>% left_join(lktState) %>% select(-abb) %>% spread(var, name)`

Comment: @sotos Note that requires the `tidyr` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

base R version (which can be vectorized but this illustrates the concept):

```
xdf <- data.frame(
  Q1= c('AL', NA, 'TX', 'FL'),
  Q2 = c('MN', 'CO', NA, NA),
  value = c(10, 24, 12, 54),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
) -> xdf

xdf
##     Q1   Q2 value
## 1   AL   MN    10
## 2 <NA>   CO    24
## 3   TX <NA>    12
## 4   FL <NA>    54
lktState <- setNames(state.name, state.abb)

xdf$Q1 <- lktState[xdf$Q1]
xdf$Q2 <- lktState[xdf$Q2]

xdf
##        Q1        Q2 value
## 1 Alabama Minnesota    10
## 2    <NA>  Colorado    24
## 3   Texas      <NA>    12
## 4 Florida      <NA>    54
```

"tidyverse"

```
library(dplyr)

xdf <- data_frame(
  Q1= c('AL', NA, 'TX', 'FL'),
  Q2 = c('MN', 'CO', NA, NA),
  value = c(10, 24, 12, 54)
) -> xdf

xdf
## # A tibble: 4 x 3
##      Q1    Q2 value
##   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
## 1    AL    MN    10
## 2  <NA>    CO    24
## 3    TX  <NA>    12
## 4    FL  <NA>    54
lktState <- setNames(state.name, state.abb)

mutate_at(xdf, .vars=vars(-value), .funs=funs(lktState[.]))
## # A tibble: 4 x 3
##        Q1        Q2 value
##     <chr>     <chr> <dbl>
## 1 Alabama Minnesota    10
## 2    <NA>  Colorado    24
## 3   Texas      <NA>    12
## 4 Florida      <NA>    54
```

There's no need to use "apply"-like idioms to do this basic lookup table assignment.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Sotos that a join is the natural way to do this. However, your `purrr` solution is definitely fixable.

You are missing three things,

1. For anything other than a simple single function, you need to use `funs` in `mutate_at`.
2. `map` functions use `~` notation for anonymous functions.
3. You don't want to return a list, but rather a character vector, so use `_chr` variant.

.

```
mutate_at(df,
          vars('Q1', 'Q2'), 
          funs(purrr::map_chr(.x = ., ~lktState$name[match(.x, lktState$abb)])))
```

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
>        Q1        Q2 value
>     <chr>     <chr> <dbl>
> 1 Alabama Minnesota    10
> 2    <NA>  Colorado    24
> 3   Texas      <NA>    12
> 4 Florida      <NA>    54
> ```

#### Data

```
df <- data_frame(Q1= c('AL', NA, 'TX', 'FL'), Q2=c('MN', 'CO', NA, NA), value=c(10,24,12,54))
```