# R - left join (merge) onto a portion of data (i.e. those with missing labels)?

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, left-join, purrr

I have a large dataset of patients with their medical records.

Almost all have a MainSpecialtyCode, but the corresponding MainSpecialtyDescription is more sparse.

I have a specialty dictionary for this, but I want to keep already existing descriptions, regardless of whether they match the dictionary. **I don't wont to overwrite existing descriptions.**

**Is is possible to do a left join only on those with missing labels?**

Or do I need to split data, and merge back as I've done below.

I wonder if there is a one-step alternative to do this.

```
  library(dplyr)

  # Mock data
  set.seed(1)
  MyData <- data.frame(
   patientID = c(LETTERS[seq(from=1, to=10)]),
   MainSpecialtyCode = c(1,2,3,4,6,11,8,1,2,3),
   MainSpecialtyDescription = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Geriatric", "Nursing", 
   "Cardiology","Nephrology", NA, NA)
  )
  SpecialtyDictionary <- data.frame(
   MainSpecialtyCode = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
   MainSpecialtyDescription = c("Cardiology", "Nephrology", "Respiratory", 
   "Cancer", "General", "Paediatric", "Urinary", "Diabetes", "Podiatry",  
   "Nursing")
  )

  # Subset data with missing descriptions
  MissingData <- MyData[is.na(MyData$MainSpecialtyDescription), ]

  # Merge descriptions onto this
  MergedData <- MissingData %>% 
    select(-MainSpecialtyDescription) %>% 
    left_join(SpecialtyDictionary, by="MainSpecialtyCode")

  # Append onto data without missing descriptions
  MyData2 <- rbind(MyData[!is.na(MyData$MainSpecialtyDescription), ], MergedData)
```

Comment: In your dictionary code for `Nursing` is 10, but in `MyData` it's 11. Is that a typo?

Comment: @utubun No it is deliberate - I want to keep existing descriptions even if they are wrong. Basically, I don't want to overwrite existing descriptions in MyData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Purrr` might be a better package for this, but one way to do this with `dplyr` could be:

```
MyData %>% 
    filter(is.na(MainSpecialtyDescription)) %>% # deal only with NAs
    select(-MainSpecialtyDescription) %>% # remove column to be overwritten
    left_join(SpecialtyDictionary, by = "MainSpecialtyCode") %>% # get the values from dictionary
    bind_rows(MyData %>%  
                  filter(!is.na(MainSpecialtyDescription))) # bind the result to the original input
```

Yields:

```
> MyData %>% 
+     filter(is.na(MainSpecialtyDescription)) %>% 
+     select(-MainSpecialtyDescription) %>% 
+     left_join(SpecialtyDictionary, by = "MainSpecialtyCode") %>% 
+     bind_rows(MyData %>%  filter(!is.na(MainSpecialtyDescription)))
   patientID MainSpecialtyCode MainSpecialtyDescription
1          A                 1               Cardiology
2          B                 2               Nephrology
3          C                 3              Respiratory
4          D                 4                   Cancer
5          I                 2               Nephrology
6          J                 3              Respiratory
7          E                 6                Geriatric
8          F                11                  Nursing
9          G                 8               Cardiology
10         H                 1               Nephrology
```

EDIT: Here is an alternative solution using `purrr::map`, as requested by OP:

```
MyData %>% 
    mutate(MainSpecialtyDescription = as.character(MainSpecialtyDescription)) %>% 
    mutate(MainSpecialtyDescription = 
           ifelse(is.na(MainSpecialtyDescription),
           purrr::map_chr(.x = .$MainSpecialtyCode, ~ as.character(SpecialtyDictionary$MainSpecialtyDescription[match(.x, SpecialtyDictionary$MainSpecialtyCode)])), 
           MainSpecialtyDescription))
```

Yields:

```
> MyData %>% 
+     mutate(MainSpecialtyDescription = as.character(MainSpecialtyDescription)) %>% 
+     mutate(MainSpecialtyDescription = 
+            ifelse(is.na(MainSpecialtyDescription),
+            purrr::map_chr(.x = .$MainSpecialtyCode, ~ as.character(SpecialtyDictionary$MainSpecialtyDescription[match(.x, SpecialtyDictionary$MainSpecialtyCode)])), 
+            MainSpecialtyDescription))
   patientID MainSpecialtyCode MainSpecialtyDescription
1          A                 1               Cardiology
2          B                 2               Nephrology
3          C                 3              Respiratory
4          D                 4                   Cancer
5          E                 6                Geriatric
6          F                11                  Nursing
7          G                 8               Cardiology
8          H                 1               Nephrology
9          I                 2               Nephrology
10         J                 3              Respiratory
```

Note the conversion of factors to strings.
The advantage is that you get by with specifying the condition only once.

Credit should go mostly here: [How can I use purrr to match records from a lookup table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117199/how-can-i-use-purrr-to-match-records-from-a-lookup-table)

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, would you mind sharing how to use purrr package for this?

Comment: Glad it works for you one way or another. The only "trick" in addition to the already published solution for mapping lookup tables with `purrr::map` is the conditional `mutate`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, I will be needing to use lots of lookup tables, so this is really handy. I will have a further read of how the purrr package works